# Mount HFS+ under Arch Linux ARM

Tags: archlinux, mount, hard-drive

I'm trying to mount an external HDD that's formatted with an HFS+ (journaled) partition. `community/hfsprogs` has been installed, but `mount -t hfsplus /dev/sda3 /mnt` returns `mount: unknown filesystem type 'hfsplus'`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to install [hfsutils](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hfsutils/)

Comment: Thanks @mpromonet, that solved it.
For others' reference, it seems both hfsprogs and hfsutils need to be installed for read-write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install [hfsutils](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hfsutils/) that is provided in the [Arch User Repository (AUR)](https://aur.archlinux.org/).

The hfsutils package could be built using :

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel 
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hf/hfsutils/hfsutils.tar.gz
tar xvzf hfsutils.tar.gz
cd hfsutils
makepkg -Acs
```

Next the package could be installed with :

```
sudo pacman -U hfsutils-*.pkg.tar.xz
```

Then the command `grep hfsplus /proc/filesystems` should report `hfsplus` and you should be able to mount an hfsplus filessystem.

Comment: today use `git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/hfsutils.git` instead of `wget ...`

Comment: or you could use an [aur helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AUR_helpers), for example, `yay -S hfsutils`